# System.ExecutionEngineException in DBContext Constructor

Tags: c#, clr, autofac

I know this is a very vague error, but I've posted on the EF Core and CLR git repositories, and they have no idea. I wonder if this might have something to do with dependency injection (I'm using AutoFac).

The error happens about every other time I start a new debugging session. It happens in the constructor of my class which inherits from DbContext, when I am passing the DbContextOptions down to the base.

**Exception:**

Exception Type: System.ExecutionEngineException

Exception Message="Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown."

Stack trace: Empty

```
protected WinsDbContextBase(DbContextOptions options, ICurrentUserContext userContext)
    : base(options) <=== the error occurs on this line
    {
... other code here ...
    }
```

I know this is not really enough to go on, but I'm posting this here in hopes that maybe someone else has experienced this and can give me a clue as to where to start digging.

**Edit:** This came down to a known bug in the CLR and is scheduled to be fixed in 4.8 framework build. The workaround was to add the following to my Machine.config file:

```
<configuration>
        <runtime>
          <disableNativeImageLoad>
            <assemblyIdentity name="netstandard" />
          </disableNativeImageLoad>
        </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/22137

Comment: It Causes when compiling 64 bit project and use it from a 32 bit environment.Check your IIS and project to be same 64 or 32, update your application to .net 4.0 or 4.5 because that exception is obsolete and check it you are not using unmanaged library, check threadpool objects and try to disable concurrent garbage collection, at all it's thrown when a fatal error detecting in  execution of clr... and don't blame me for my bad english

Comment: @NaDeRStar thanks for the advice. I would never blame you for bad English, I'm sure your English is better than my Farsi :-)

I'm using .Net 4.6.2 in all projects, I have my web startup project set to use IIS 64 bit, and I'm running on a 64 bit OS (Windows 10).

Comment: If you found a solution to the problem, please place it as an answer in the form below, rather than inside the question.

Comment: Thanks E_net4. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This came down to a known bug in the CLR and is scheduled to be fixed in 4.8 framework build. The workaround was to add the following to my Machine.config file:

```
<configuration>
        <runtime>
          <disableNativeImageLoad>
            <assemblyIdentity name="netstandard" />
          </disableNativeImageLoad>
        </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/22137